# Migration from Rest(Express) to GraphQL: Models(mongoose) don't work in graphQL resolvers

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, graphql, apollo

Thank you for your attention!

I decided to transfer my REST API(Express) to GraphGL.
Everything worked before adding subscribers.
Now all models return Timeout:
[image]
[image]

Resolvers:
[image]

If I clean the model, then it can return something to me:
[image]
[image]

Here is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-cohen-7o74v?file=/models/owner.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

...

 // mongoose
 mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DB_HOST, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```